# Python - Função com retorno incorreto

Tags: python-3.x

O código abaixo é um exemplo simplista, mas que representa exatamente o erro que está dando no meu código oficial.

```
    def MontarURL(self):
    URL = "C:\\Users\\tttt\\Desktop\\Imagens\\2.png"
    return (URL)

    A = MontarURL
    print (A)
```

O retorno deveria ser uma URL e retorna algo tipo isso: **function principal.MontarURL at 0x038EB390**. O que não é apenas um problema de exibição, porque vou precisar dessa URL do jeito normal dela para uma outra função.

Como faço para que retorne exatamente o que deve e não apenas o endereçamento da memória onde o objeto se encontra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está chamando a função corretamente, tente dessa forma:

```
def MontarURL():
    URL = "C:\\Users\\tttt\\Desktop\\Imagens\\2.png"
    return (URL)
# Você precisa chamar a função dessa forma, senão vai 
#retornar o endereço de memória bem como você já descobriu
A = MontarURL()
print (A)
```

Comment: O interessante é que funcionou, mas, ainda assim, o PyCharm aponta como errado por estar faltando self da função.

Comment: se essa função estiver dentro de uma classe, realmente é necessário o self.